# Geolocation API - Is there a way to make random locations each time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, google-geolocation

I currently have a map app that is supposed to give random locations on each press - however I am often met with 'ZERO_RESULTS'

The method part

```
int randomIndex = arc4random() % [arr_OfCountryCode count];

        
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false,+CA&key=MY_GOOGLE_KEY",[arr_OfCountryCode objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
```

The array of CountryCodes are;

```
arr_OfCountryCode = @[@"AF",@"AL",@"DZ",@"AS",@"AD",@"AO",@"AI",@"AQ",@"AG",@"AR",@"AM",@"AW",@"AC",@"AU",@"AT",@"AZ",@"BS",@"BH",@"BD",@"BB",@"BY",@"BE",@"BZ",@"BJ",@"BM",@"BT",@"BO",@"BA",@"BW",@"BV",@"BR",@"IO",@"VG",@"BN",@"BG",@"BF",@"BI",@"KH",@"CM",@"CA",@"IC",@",CV",@"BQ",@"KY",@"CF",@"EA",@"TD",@"CL",@"CN",@"CX",@"CP",@"CC",@"CO",@"KM",@"CD",@"CG",@"CK",@"CR",@"HR",@"CU",@"CW",@"CY",@"CZ",@"CI",@"DK",@"DG",@"DJ",@"DM",@"DO",@"EC",@"EG",@"SV",@"GQ",@"ER",@"EE",@"ET",@"FK",@"FO",@"FJ",@"FI",@"FR",@"FG",@"PF",@"TF",@"GA",@"GM",@"GE",@"DE",@"GH",@"GI",@"GR",@"GL",@"GD",@"GP",@"GU",@"GT",@"GG",@"GN",@"GW",@"GY",@"HT",@"HM",@"HN",@"HK",@"HU",@"IS",@"IN",@"ID",@"IR",@"IQ",@"IE",@"IM",@"IL",@"IT",@"JM",@"JP",@"JE",@"JO",@"KZ",@"KE",@"KI",@"XK",@"KW",@"KG",@"LA",@"LV",@"LB",@"LS",@"LR",@"LY",@"LI",@"LT",@"LU",@"MO",@"MK",@"MG",@"MW",@"MY",@"MV",@"ML",@"MT",@"MH",@"MQ",@"MR",@"MU",@"YT",@"MX",@"FM",@"MD",@"MC",@"MN",@"ME",@"MS",@"MA",@"MZ",@"MM",@"NA",@"NR",@"NP",@"NL",@"NC",@"NZ",@"NI",@"NE",@"NG",@"NU",@"NF",@"KP",@"MP",@"NO",@"OM",@"PK",@"PW",@"PS",@"PA",@"PG",@"PY",@"PE",@"PH",@"PN",@"PL",@"PT",@"PR",@"QA",@"RO",@"RU",@"RW",@"RE",@"WS",@"SM",@"SA",@"SN",@"RS",@"SC",@"SL",@"SG",@"SX",@"SK",@"SI",@"SB",@"SO",@"ZA",@"GS",@"KR",@"SS",@"ES",@"LK",@"BL",@"SH",@"KN",@"LC",@"MF",@"PM",@"VC",@"SD",@"SR",@"SJ",@"SZ",@"SE",@"CH",@"SY",@"ST",@"TW",@"TJ",@"TZ",@"TH",@"TL",@"TG",@"TK",@"TO",@"TT",@"TA",@"TN",@"TR",@"TM",@"TC",@"TV",@"UM",@"VI",@"UG",@"UA",@"AE",@"GB",@"US",@"UY",@"UZ",@"VU",@"VA",@"VE",@"VN",@"WF",@"EH",@"YE",@"ZM",@"ZW",@"AX"];
```

Ideally all I really want is to come up with a random location in any country each time, I did think this would work, but it comes up ZERO_RESULTS more times than it works...

Comment: What happens if you paste that URL string into a browser address bar?

Comment: {
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}

Comment: I don't think the two-letter "Country Code" is enough. For example, the code for **Gabon** is **GA** ... but using GA returns the State of Georgia, USA. You can test it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: That could be an issue, but this one seems to almost forget to refresh each time I pressing the map location button, the first try now always works, but each subsequent one doesn't it just brings "ZERO_RESULTS" in the debug console

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't think the Country Code alone is enough. For example: enter `JP` -- **ZERO_RESULTS** ... enter `TOKYO, JP` -- we get Tokyo, Japan. I imagine since I am in the US, entering two-letter **State** codes returns a geolocation in that state.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting... using the Country Name **does** return results. So, instead of `[@"AF",@"AL",@"DZ",...` you could use `[@"Afghanistan",@"Albania",@"Algeria",...`

Comment: Brilliant suggestion @DonMag will try this over the weekend and report back! Thank you!